# How to deal with a Co-worker with performance issues

Tags: communication, management, colleagues

I've been managing a small electronics store for a few years. I have two co-workers: the boss, and the technician.

I have a problem with the technician: he's very nice, skilled, and actually the one who got me the job in that place.

However:

- He forgets everything (from someone's repair status to the fact that there is no IPhone 7S).
- Sometimes loses phone parts; the phone lab looks like a mess and I'm the one who have to order his parts.
- He has no remote idea about how to stick to work and finish repairs at the right time and to add on that, he also gives customers wrong estimates about their phone repair. It got to the point that I had to repair phones if I wanted them to be ready in time.
- Instead of doing his actual job and researching the problem or assigning the job to the appropriate technician (we have additional technicians for more complex problems like chip replacements or computer problems, etc) he'll run ccleaner on the customer's phone/computer and send him home to see if he still have the problem.

Another big problem is that he easily could be distracted from his work. for example:

- a friend come to visit him at work and he'll talk to him for an hour.
- He'll spend half an hour talking with his friends on the phone even if I need his help with something.

I've tried to gently talk with him about a few of these issues and see how he'll react when I'm facing him with the facts but he just denied  everything and told me he does not think there's anything wrong with his work. My boss also has tried to talk to him a few times, there was a little difference but we still have the same problems.

It is simple that he's not right for the store. However, currently we don't have a good replacement and he was in the storefront since its very early days and a lot of customers like him.

I really frustrated about that:

- Should I try to face him again and again with my problems?
- Should I push the boss to replace him? He's very skilled and can sometimes really surprise everyone by fixing phone that looks unfixable.
- How to deal with the fact that he was in the store a lot before I was and even helped me get that job opportunity?

Comment: Are you this guy's boss? And what impact is he having on you or your work?

Comment: "I've tried to see how he'll react when I'm facing him with the facts but he'll just deny anything and tell me he does not think there's anything wrong." Does this mean you have spoken to him about these issues you have? Or does this mean that you have thought about having a conversation and are anticipating his reaction?

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm not his boss; But I have to make sure he gets his job done (remind him lightly get back to work; but it is not my job).

Comment: @Cypher Sorry, I'll edit this part. I did spoke to him about some of these issues.

Comment: How are you tracking the customer repairs now? How do you organize phone parts now? I'm asking because you might have an organization problem and the tech has to remember too much stuff.

Comment: @jcmack We have a software especially for that. Every phone gets a printed sticker with its details. Every part has a sticker with its name and the model it is for.

Comment: hmm, could the downvoter post a comment? I did put a effort and wrote a detailed question.

Answer (score 4):

The best option is a job tracking system enforced by the boss. You don't have the authority to enforce anything and you have tried gentle reminders. So a tracking system is the best option.

Comment: Thanks! Can you detail a little more? We do track repairs with a software and also have online cameras all over the store.

Comment: So use it and enforce it. All work going through my office is tracked from start to finish, I skim through everything and it's easy to spot what is taking too long at which point I'll put up more detail and rectify it. If you don't monitor and enforce it, it's a waste of time. If someone is consistently not keeping up then that wll be reflected in their review and pay rise. Tracking system is the main tool for reviewing a persons work when looking at pay raises or discipline.